# makefile: No rule to make target '%.o'

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, mingw

I have 3 files: Source.cpp 2ndfile.cpp 2ndfile.hpp
And I'm trying to compile them with mingw32-make

**makefile that doesn't work:**

```
all: launch.exe

launch.exe: %.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $< -std=gnu++11
```

**makefile that works:**

```
all: launch.exe

launch.exe: source.o 2ndfile.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

source.o: source.cpp
    g++ -c source.cpp -std=gnu++11

2ndfile.o: 2ndfile.cpp
    g++ -c 2ndfile.cpp -std=gnu++11
```

**My question is:** why the first one doesn't work? What's my problem with '%' patterns?
The error I get: `mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '%.o', needed by 'launch.exe'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **My question is**: why the first one doesn't work? What's my problem with '%' patterns?

A pattern rule matches targets to prerequisites via a common element in their names, represented by the `%` wildcard.  You present your own example in the form of this rule:

> ```
> %.o: %.cpp
>     g++ -c $< -std=gnu++11
> ```

On the other hand, this rule ...

> ```
> launch.exe: %.o
>     g++ -o $@ $^
> ```

... is *not* a pattern rule, because the target name does not contain a `%`.  There, you seem to be trying to use `%` in an entirely different sense, analogous to `*` in a glob pattern.  It does not serve that purpose, even in pattern rules.  That would give pattern rules a very different (and much less useful) meaning.  Instead, in your non-pattern rule, the `%` is treated as an ordinary character.

There are many ways to write makefiles, but a good, simple model to start from for exploring pattern rules would be a combination of your first and second examples:

```
all: launch.exe

launch.exe: source.o 2ndfile.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $< -std=gnu++11
```

Comment: mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'source.o', needed by 'launch.exe'.  Stop.

Comment: Then either you are not using GNU make, or the file `source.cpp` is not present in the working directory, @vamirio-chan

Comment: But the 2nd example works (which has exact names of files). Also if you substitute % with * it works as well. I'm using "mingw32-make" command in dir w/ files.

EDIT: Found my mistake: source -> Source. Your advice w/ targets helped, thanks.

Comment: The example makefile I present works fine for me, @vamirio-chan, with dummy source files.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute % with *.

```
all: launch.exe

launch.exe: *.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

*.o: *.cpp
    g++ -c $^ -std=gnu++11
```

**EDIT**: there's an answer below why this is a bad idea. Here's what works:

```
all: launch.exe

launch.exe: Source.o 2ndfile.o
    g++ -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $^ -std=gnu++11
```

Comment: This is poor advice, because it risks picking up object files other than the ones you want, and *it doesn't work* on the first build or if any of the needed `.o` files are removed.